# Can't send id to resource controller destroy function in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: 
    {
      "Delete Student": function(event) 
      {
         event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({

         type: "POST",
         data: {
            id: "$(this).data('studentId')",
            _method: "DELETE",
         },
         url: "{{ route('students.destroy') }}",
         success: function(result) {
            alert('ok');
         },
         error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
         }
      });
         $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function()
      {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
});

$(".deleteButton").on("click",function()
{
    $("#dialog-confirm").data('studentId',$(this).closest("td").find("input[name='studentId']").val()).dialog("open");
});
```

I have this code to delete the student after confirmation via dialog box. I want to send id of student to destroy function(working fine coz I have checked by deleting student without dialog box first) of StudentController. I have also tried `url:"URL::route('students.destroy')"` or `url:"URL::to('/students/')"`
 but nothing working. By inspecting,
 [this error is coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw7P6.jpg) Please help, any type of suggestions to delete the student would be welcome but dialog box is must ... :)

Comment: `"$(this).data('studentId')"`  You have quotes around you're command making it a string, not a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing a delete pass the id as a url param instead of post data and url a normal url and pass the id to that.

```
var id = $(this).data('studentId');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        _method: "DELETE",
    },
    url: '/students/destroy/'+id,
    success: function(result) {
        alert('ok');
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir your answer certainly worked for me.My way of adding url was not right but I would want to make one improvement in ur answer. As I said it is resource Controller, so url would be only '/students/'+id and no need of destroy...thanks

Answer (score 0):

BTW: method: "DELETE" must be in the first node of first ajax function arguments so you don't need the form method spoofing (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing)

```
$.ajax({
         method: "DELETE",
         data:{...},
         ...
```

AND

the route helper function needs the id for your student model instance:

```
{{ route('students.destroy', [$student->id]) }}
```

but only in a Blade file so you mix php syntax with HTML/JS or whatever

(I really dislike this JS in Blade, but sometimes for very local unique "problems" it is the quickest solution, hopefully "cut and dry")